# How do I change a Boolean variable's value from a grandchild component in this Vue 3 application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am working on a *Vue 3* app. I have 3 nested components: a button component, which is nested inside a navigation component, which is nested inside a content component.

The button should toggle the value of the boolean variable `isVisible` inside the grandparent component `Main.vue` (content component).

In the grandchild component `MyButton.vue`:

```
<template>
  <button @click="handleClick" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
    {{ label }}
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyButton',
  props: {
    label: String,
    isVisible: Boolean
  },

  emits: [
    'toggleVisibility',
],
  
   methods: {
    handleClick() {
      this.$emit('toggleVisibility')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In the parent component `Navigation.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div class="navigation">
        <MyButton 
            :label='"Toggle content"' 
            :isVisible=false 
            @toggleVisibility="$emit('toggleVisibility')"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import MyButton from './MyButton'

    export default {
       emits: [
        'toggleVisibility',
       ],
    }
</script>
```

In the grandparent component `Main.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <Navigation />

    <div v-if="isVisible" class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import Navigation from './Ui/Navigation'

export default {
  name: 'Main',
  components: {
        Navigation
    },
  props: {
    title: String,
    tagline: String,
  },
  
  data() {
    return {
      isVisible: false,
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    toggleVisibility() {
        console.log('ok');
        this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### The problem

As can be seen above, I tried to emit upwards, *one component at a time*.

For a reason I was unable to understand, this does *not* work.

##### Questions

1. Where is my mistake?
2. What is the shortest viable solution?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-starter-6gel5j?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 You didn't declare `MyButton` component in you parent `Navigation` component.
      Add this inside `export default {}`

```
components: {
   MyButton
},
```

#2 You aren't listening to the event in you grand parent `Main` component.
      Replace the `<Navigation />` line with:

```
<Navigation @toggleVisibility="toggleVisibility" />
```

P.S: Prefer `kebab-case` for custom defined events. Just a best practice. `toggle-visiblity` instead of `toggleVisibility`